# Identical observations in linear regression

Tags: regression

I want to do a linear regression $Y = X\beta + e$, but some of the observations (rows in $X$) are identical (about 30 000 out of 50 000 remain after deleting all duplicates), so when I try to calculate the OLS estimate $\hat{\beta} = (X^t X)^{-1} X^t Y$, the matrix $(X^t X)^{-1}$ is singular. How do I remedy this?

Comment: Are you using software? There may be a built-in [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) routine, which is the replacement of $(X^tX)^{-1}X^t$ that you need here.

Comment: Often $ X $ is a skinny matrix and has a trivial nullspace, even if some of the rows of $ X $ are duplicates. What is the shape of $ X$ in your problem? Duplicate rows in $ X$ does not necessarily imply that $ X^T X $ is singular.

Comment: It does not make sense that X'X was non-singular prior to the duplicate drop and singular after the drop. If you have a linear combination of the columns, then adding the same observation over and over should not change that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and more equations than variables, thus $m > n$. 
We want to know when

$$
X^t X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$
is invertible. One critera is that $\ker X^t X = \{ 0 \}$. This means
$$
0 = X^t X  u = \sum_j (X^t X)_{.j} u_j
$$
only holds for $u = 0$, in other words the columns of $X^t X$ are
linear independent.

$$
0 = X^t X u \Rightarrow \\
0 = u^t X^t X u = (X u)^t (X u) = \lVert X u \rVert^2 \Rightarrow \\
X u = 0.
$$
So $X$ must be such, that $u = 0$ follows from $X u = 0$. Using the same arguments as for $X^t X$, this is the case if the columns of $X$ are linear independent thus if $\mbox{rank } X = n$.

This means:

- If $X$ had linear independent columns, adding or removing copies of
  existing rows will give a new matrix $X$ with the same property.
  The only positive effect of this clean up might be saving memory
  and speeding up the calculation. 
  It has no impact on $X^t X$ being singular or not.
- If $X^t X$ is not invertible, then the column rank $r$ of $X$, which
  is equal to the row rank of $X$, must be smaller than $n$. This can
  be changed if $n-r$ rows are added that bring the resulting $X$ to
  $\mbox{rank } X = n$. Thus it seems you have not too much information,
  but instead lack information.
- If it is not possible to add those rows, another option might be to
  drop unknowns, reducing $n$ towards $r$, if the correct ones are
  dropped. Gauss elimination either on $X$ or $X^t$ should reveal the
  ones.
- Here are some remarks about the computation of the rank:
  [computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Computation)

Comment: If such duplicates exist it probably is terrible idea as little information can be found. Also, which linear combination should you keep?

Comment: $X$ is not a square matrix.

Comment: $\det(X^t X) = \det(X^t) \det(X)$ assumes that $X$ is square.

Comment: And another update. Too late now to dabble further.